# In the EU, with GDPR in force, can a company refuse service if a customer doesn't want marketing emails?

Tags: gdpr

I am having an argument with a local discount airline in the EU:

They have been sending 3 up-sell emails for a single flight. Under GDPR, it is my right to revoke any consent to receive marketing material.

Their argument is that email is an all or nothing and if I opt-out of marketing emails, I will not receive purchase confirmations, etc.

I am wondering if this is legal under GDPR to limit service because I refuse to receive marketing emails.

Comment: AFAIK GDPR forbids a company to give different treatment if you do not allow them to get your data. IANAL.

Comment: as an airline, they have my data anyways; the issue is that they claim that email is an all or nothing

Comment: Related questions: [Do marketing emails require consent?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/29062/18215) and [GDPR: Receiving marketing as precondition for receiving a free service, legitimate interest?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/28599/18215)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they can't do that. [GDPR Recital 42](https://gdpr.eu/Recital-42-Burden-of-proof-and-requirements-for-consent/) states:

> Consent should not be regarded as freely given if the data subject has
>   no genuine or free choice or is unable to refuse or withdraw consent
>   without detriment.

Here's some more context on [consent requirements](https://gdpr.eu/gdpr-consent-requirements/).